# MSWord VBA UserForm Disable Modal So I Can Copy Text from Other Applications

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using VBA for MS-WORD.  It works great.  The problem is that I need to manually copy text from other word documents and other applications to enter into the User Form.  But the User Form is a Modal so I can't click outside of it to do this.

Is there any way that I can disable this restriction so that I can open the user form, go to another document, copy some text and then come back and paste it into my user form?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can do the following when showing the form to make it Modeless and allow interaction with Word while the modal is open:

```
myFormName.Show vbModeless
```

I'm using the Mac Version of Word right now, and that's not working, but I saw somewhere that they don't allow Modeless modals for the Mac 2011 version of Word.